# Pass data between components that are not related on react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, components, state

i'm doing a app and i have an ajax call that send the data to the server and ask the db,it retrieves me the object data.Until here everything is cool.But i want to do a route with routie to retrieve the results on it'own page. the problem is that the two component are at the same level on the hierarchy, so cant get the props of the state data . I've heard about flux but it's a pretty complex architecture for the project that i'm doing. Do you guys have a good pattern to solve that ?

Very Gratefull ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need Flux for this. You can not (or at least should not) pass data between Components which are on the same hierarchy level. You should read the following lines: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live

It gives you same hints on how to decide where to put your state by defining some simple rules.

Simply put the necessary logic into a common owner of your two components (so one or more level up in the hierarchy).

Comment: Ok,so i must have a container component for instance app to encompass all the components that encompass their turn the components that composes the page.But if i do that i have to destroy the component that represent the older page no?

Comment: What if i do an owner components thats it's just here to bind the data without rendering?